# Error en variable de Salida en VHDL

Tags: variables, vhdl

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para hacer un sémaforo asíncrónico programado en VHDL utilizando Quartus II y una FPGA Cyclone IV
Al momento de compilar mi código me marca 2 errores y lanza el mensaje siguiente:

Error (10309): VHDL Interface Declaration error in semaforo.vhd(39): interface object "verde2" of mode out cannot be read. Change object mode to buffer.

Error (10309): VHDL Interface Declaration error in semaforo.vhd(39): interface object "ama2" of mode out cannot be read. Change object mode to buffer.

El código es el siguiente

```
library IEEE;
```

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity semaforo2 is
Port (
D, EN, clk, reset: in  std_logic;
verde1, verde2, ama1, ama2, rojo1, rojo2: out std_logic
);
end semaforo2;

architecture semaforo of semaforo2 is
signal a, b, c, notA, notB, notC, nx1: std_logic;

begin
process(clk, reset)
begin
if reset = '1' then
a <= '0';
b <= '0';
c <= '0';
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
if EN = '1' then
a <= D;
b <= a;
c <= b;
end if;
end if;
end process;

```
nx1 <= not c;
notA <= not a;
notB <= not b;
notC <= not c;

verde1 <= ((notA) and (notB) and (notC)) or ((notA) and (notB) and (c));
verde2 <= ((notA) and (b) and (c)) or ((a) and (notB) and (notC));
ama1 <= ((notA) and (b) and (notC));
ama2 <= ((a) and (notB) and (c));
rojo1 <= (verde2) or (ama2);
rojo2 <= (verde1) or (ama1);
```

end semaforo;

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? :c